# Windows 7 stopped booting and showing some message on black screen

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have Lenovo g460 with Windows 7 premium 64-bit, it was working fine yesterday...but when I try to use my laptop now I see  a message on black screen

```
PXE-E61: media test failure, check cable  
pxe-mof: exiting pxe rom.  
no bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

but I don't have any installation disks except repair disk which I created through Windows wizard... I searched for solution over net and  tried to recover ..first I booted with repair disk and found operating system as unknown on local disk startup repair option found error but cannt repair it and through command prompt I tried these commands

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

the first 2 commands worked successfully but when I run the last command it scanned and identified Windows installations 1 and prompted to add it to boot list by when I press y to add I got the message

the requested system device cannot be found.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It sounds like something on your computer as failed.  Are you able to simply reinstall Windows?  You should be able to request media from Lenovo or Microsoft and use your existing key.

Comment: thanks for reply but i dont want to reinstall ...i want some solution to resolve the issue..